# How can I overrides Material UI V5 Date Pickers styles?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to override Mui X-Date-Pickers V5 by creating a theme.

This component is built on top of many others. I want to change borderColor property, but this one is set on fieldset element, so I need to drill down from MuiInputBase.

```
    MuiInputBase: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          '& > fieldset': {
            borderColor: '#000000',
          },
          '& > fieldset.MuiOutlinedInput-root:hover': {
            borderColor: 'red',
          },
        },
      },
    },
```

So I'm able to reach the fieldset and change the borderColor property. But I don't know how to hover on MuiInputBase and update borderColor on fieldset.

I have tried nesting my hover inside `& > fieldset` but still isn't working

Answer (score 1):

This is the proper way to change it as described [here](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/localization/#using-the-theme)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { AdapterDayjs } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDayjs";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";
import { DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker";

const theme = createTheme(
  {
    palette: {
      primary: { main: '#ff0000' },
    },
  },
);

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#root")).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
        <DatePicker
          label="Helper text example"
          slotProps={{
            textField: {
              helperText: "MM/DD/YYYY"
            }
          }}
        />
      </LocalizationProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Demo https://codesandbox.io/s/fs5mf2?file=/demo.tsx:1252-1281